# How to fetch posts that are stored in the different table than (default) wp_posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, loop

What I need is altering default Wordpress posts-pooling mechanism so I can get posts from other tables in database, not just default wp_posts and wp_postmeta.

How is that possible?

I'm ready to proudly die dealing with consequences of altering Wordpress core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't hack the Core. There are filters in `WP_Query` that should more than suffice to include your table, if your SQL and regex are good enough.

> - `posts_distinct` - Alters SQL 'DISTINCTROW' clause to the query that    returns the post array.
> - `posts_groupby` - Alters SQL 'GROUP BY' clause of the query that    returns the post array.
> - `posts_join` - Alters SQL 'JOIN' clause of the query that returns the    post array.
> - `post_limits` - Alters SQL 'LIMIT' clause of the query that returns the    post array.
> - `posts_orderby` - Alters SQL 'ORDER BY' clause of the query that    returns the post array.
> - `posts_where` - Alters SQL 'WHERE' clause of the query that returns the    post array.
> - `posts_join_paged` - Alters SQL paging for posts using 'JOIN' clause of    the query that returns the post array.
> - `posts_where_paged` - Alters SQL paging for posts using 'WHERE' clause    of the query that returns the post array.
> - `posts_clauses` - Alters all the SQL clauses above in one go. It gives    you an array of elements that are easy to alter
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Filters

Your question is not detailed enough for a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks. It will take some time to to check this and, and I'll accept your answer

Comment: I will accept your answer to rewart your efforts, but I must ask one more (much more detailed ) question regarding this issue.